# Execute Code with Env Var Set Temporarily

Tags: org-babel, environment

Here's a piece of C++ code (its content is not important) written in an Org file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC C++
  #include <omp.h>
  #include <iostream>

  int main() {
  #pragma omp parallel
      std::cout << omp_get_thread_num();
      std::cout << std::endl;
  }
#+END_SRC

# Local Variables:
# eval: (require 'ob-C)
# org-babel-C++-compiler: "g++.exe  \
#                           -std=c++20 -Wall -O0  \
#                           -fopenmp "
# End:
```

The **output of this C++ program depends on the env variable** `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

How can I tell Org to execute this code block with `OMP_NUM_THREADS` set to some specific value?  
So that when I press `C-c C-c` it behaves like (for example, `OMP_NUM_THREADS=5`):

```
PS tmp> g++.exe -std=c++20 -Wall -O0  `
>>       -fopenmp  `
>>       ./a.cpp -o ./a.exe  `
>>      &&  `
>>      Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait  `
>>       -Environment @{OMP_NUM_THREADS=5}  `
>>       -FilePath ./a.exe
```

Comment: How/where do you specify how to run the program (the `Start-Process` stuff)? AFAICT, there is no way to customize that: the executor just concatenates the binary with the rest of the command line specified in the header. Also, I take it this is on Windows? Unix/Linux would be fairly simple, although it would still require code changes.

Comment: @NickD “*How/where do you specify how to run the program (the `Start-Process` stuff)?*” -- I expect something like `#+BEGIN_SRC C++ :SetVarWhenExec "VAR=VAL"`. (The question just takes `Start-Process` as an example to clarify what I want. Any statement like `VAR=VAL cmd` in Bash can be used as an example.) ||| “*the executor just concatenates the binary with the rest of the command line specified in the header.*” -- What does the header stand for? (I'm new to `org-babel`; not quite familiar with it.) ||| “*Also, I take it this is on Windows?*” -- Yes.

Comment: See [C,D,C++ language specific features](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C.html) for some info (not much). You still have to look in the code to find out what's happening. Some effort has been taken to provide enough options to *compile* simple programs (e.g. the `:includes` and `:libs` headers) but not much has been done to enable *running* the executable in different ways. See [org-babel-C-execute](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ob-C.el#n174): all it's doing is calling `org-babel-eval` on `(concat tmp-bin-file cmdline)`.

Comment: If `VAR=VAL cmd` is enough even on Windows, then the code change I was thinking about is to add an `:envvars` header (and it can be in common code, since it will be useful for every babel implementation) and change the `concat` to do `(concat envvars tmp-bin-file cmdline)` instead (that would require a change in every language implementation eventually). But I don't think anything like that exists today.

Comment: @NickD Okay, I think I should submit a feature request. Actually, creating a macro that temporarily modifies environment variables (using functions like `getenv` and `setenv`) could make it cross-platform without worrying about the type of shell. BTW, thanks for the link (actually, I’m writing notes for my parallel computing class, and all the pieces of sample code use the `omp.h` library; adding it to `org-babel-default-header-args:C++` will save me a lot of time)!

Answer (score 2):

This is my current workaround (so it's not actually an answer IMO):

> `#+BEGIN_SRC` `C++` `:results` `none`
>
> ```cpp
>   #pragma omp parallel
>       cout << 0 << 1;
> ```
>
> `#+END_SRC`
>
> `#+BEGIN_SRC` `emacs-lisp`
>
> ```lisp
>   (save-excursion
>     (org-previous-block 1)
>     (with-environment-variables (("OMP_NUM_THREADS" "5"))
>       (org-babel-execute-src-block)))
> ```
>
> `#+END_SRC`

Not pretty.
It doesn't prevent the user (me) from running the first piece of code directly (and I want the user to only run the second piece of code, always).

Comment: `with-environment-variables`

Comment: @rpluim: Thx! I didn't know this before. I’ve updated the answer (and my notes ;)